# Get display name from web.xml file

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to get the Display name (Context Root) from web.xml file to avoid hardcoding a context root.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`ServletContext.getServletContextName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletContextName())

> Returns the name of this web
>   application corresponding to this
>   ServletContext as specified in the
>   deployment descriptor for this web
>   application by the display-name
>   element.

Comment: As @BalusC mentioned. One should use getContextPath(). Because the context root is different thatn Context name.

Answer (score 12):

There's some ambiguity in your question. The "display name" is **not** the same as "context root". To get the `<display-name>` value from `web.xml`, look at skaffman's answer in this question. To get the `<Context path>` value from `context.xml`, use [`ServletContext#getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath%28%29). This is often referenced as "context root" (which you also see in the URL, that part immediately after domain).

Comment: You are right. It should be .getContextPath() not getServletContextName().

Answer (score 1):

En nombre puede obtener de la clase ServletContext.
Con JSF

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ServletContext servletContext= (ServletContext) externalContext.getContext();
System.out.println("Context Name: "+servletContext.getServletContextName());
```

Or Within a Servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
ServletContext servletContext= getServletContext();
System.out.println("Context Name: "+servletContext.getServletContextName());
}
```